# Creating loop syntax with a count variable (SPSS)

Tags: loops, syntax, count

I have a longitudinal (person-level) dataset I am looking to for syntax for counting the number of times an event happened up to a certain point. More specifically I have 200 weeks of data (each week is coded 1-7, I'm only interested in weeks where the value is 5 or greater),  But I am only interested in weeks that happened before a certain time point (the time point is different for each person but and captured under a single variable "eventweek").  So for person Y whose eventweek = 154, I want to know what percentage of weeks before week 154 (wks 1-153) where that person was coded a 5 or above. For person Z whose eventweek = 52, I want to know what percentage of weeks before week 52 (wks 1-51) for which that person was coded a 5 or above, and so on.

Any ideas on how to code this?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: ooops! meant to specify SPSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
vector v = week1 to week200.
compute #z = 0.
loop #i = 1 to (eventweek -1).
compute #z = #z + (v(#i) ge 5).
end loop.
compute ew_perc = #z/(eventweek -1)*100.
exe.
```